# Why am I getting 'Call to unconfigured method' when using wrapped functionality?

Tags: c#, fakeiteasy

Using version 7.3.0 of FakeItEasy.
In following code I am getting message that call to method GetById is not configured, yet I am configuring it. What I am doing wrong?
There is no overload for the GetById method.

```cs
var fakeConnection = A.Fake<IEventStoreConnection>();
var fakeResolver = A.Fake<IEventResolver>();
var logger = A.Fake<ILogger<DummyAggregateRepository>>();

var repository = new DummyAggregateRepository(fakeConnection, fakeResolver, logger);

var fakeRepository = A.Fake<DummyAggregateRepository>(
    o =>
    {
        o.Wrapping(repository);
        o.Strict();
    });

var aggregateId = Guid.NewGuid();

A.CallTo(() => fakeRepository.GetById(aggregateId, A<CancellationToken>._))
    .CallsWrappedMethod();

var fixture = new AutoFixture.Fixture();

var events1 = fixture.CreateMany<DummyAggregate.EventOne>(10).Cast<Event>();
var events2 = fixture.CreateMany<DummyAggregate.EventTwo>(10).Cast<Event>();

var events = events1.Union(events2).ToList();

A.CallTo(
        () => fakeRepository.GetEvents(
            "dummyAggregate-" + aggregateId.ToString("N"),
            aggregateId.ToString(),
            A<CancellationToken>._))
    .Returns(events);

var aggregate = await fakeRepository.GetById(aggregateId, default);
```

GetById implementation is virtual method

```
public virtual async Task<TAggregate> GetById(Guid aggregateId, CancellationToken ct)
        {
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            var streamName = this.GetStreamName(aggregateId);

            using var scope = EventStoreCommon.CreateScope(Tracer.Instance, nameof(this.GetById), streamName);

            var events = await this.GetEvents(streamName, aggregateId.ToString(), ct);

            if (events.Any() == false)
            {
                throw new AggregateNotFoundException(aggregateId, typeof(TAggregate));
            }

            var aggregate = new TAggregate();

            foreach (var @event in events)
            {
                aggregate.ApplyEvent(@event);
            }

            return aggregate;
        }
```

Error reported

```
FakeItEasy.ExpectationException: Call to unconfigured method of strict fake: MyCompany.EventStore.Test.AggregateRepositoryTests.DummyAggregateRepository...

FakeItEasy.ExpectationException
Call to unconfigured method of strict fake: MyCompany.EventStore.Test.AggregateRepositoryTests.DummyAggregateRepository.GetById(aggregateId: d8d0445d-7f82-4636-82fc-2e8f14be7f3d, ct: System.Threading.CancellationToken).
   at FakeItEasy.Core.StrictFakeRule.Apply(IInterceptedFakeObjectCall fakeObjectCall) in C:\projects\fakeiteasy\src\FakeItEasy\Core\StrictFakeRule.cs:line 53
   at FakeItEasy.Core.FakeManager.ApplyBestRule(IInterceptedFakeObjectCall fakeObjectCall) in C:\projects\fakeiteasy\src\FakeItEasy\Core\FakeManager.cs:line 276
   at FakeItEasy.Core.FakeManager.FakeItEasy.Core.IFakeCallProcessor.Process(InterceptedFakeObjectCall fakeObjectCall) in C:\projects\fakeiteasy\src\FakeItEasy\Core\FakeManager.cs:line 178
   at FakeItEasy.Creation.CastleDynamicProxy.CastleDynamicProxyGenerator.ProxyInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation) in C:\projects\fakeiteasy\src\FakeItEasy\Creation\CastleDynamicProxy\CastleDynamicProxyGenerator.cs:line 187
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.DummyAggregateRepositoryProxy.GetById(Guid aggregateId, CancellationToken ct)
   at MyCompany.EventStore.Test.AggregateRepositoryTests.GetByIdTests.When_Stream_Exists_Should_Create_Instance_Of_Aggregate_With_Applied_Events() in C:\github\MyCompany_2\libraries\eventstore\test\MyCompany.EventStore.Test\AggregateRepositoryTests\GetByIdTests.cs:line 131
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__139_0(Object state)
   at Xunit.Sdk.AsyncTestSyncContext.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<Post>b__1(Object _) in C:\Dev\xunit\xunit\src\xunit.execution\Sdk\AsyncTestSyncContext.cs:line 75
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated after getting new code and stack trace. Original answer left below**

I think it's a bug.

Boring explanation:

`Strict` and `Wrapping` each add rules to the front of the faked object's rules list. The rules apply to all incoming calls. The first rule found that matches a call is triggered. So in your configuration, `Wrapping` is added making the Fake attempt to forward all calls to the wrapped object. Then `Strict`, so now the Fake will reject all calls.

You'd then expect

```cs
A.CallTo(() => fakeRepository.GetById(aggregateId, A<CancellationToken>._))
    .CallsWrappedMethod();
```

to add a rule that would cause an incoming matching `GetById` call to be forwarded to the wrapped method, but the [implementation of CallsWrappedMethod](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/blob/cd162869f824dae5dbbb460cd076d4a8813d2ad9/src/FakeItEasy/Configuration/RuleBuilder.cs#L119-L130)

appears to be missing a `this.AddRuleIfNeeded()` call around line 127. (You can see that `CallsBaseMethod` just above has this call.)

I've verified that no rule is added by the `CallsWrappedMethod` configuration. Likely has been broken since implemented in [FakeItEasy 6.0.0](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/releases/tag/6.0.0) (issue [#1717](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/1717)).

I created [issue #1870](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/1870) **which is now fixed and released as part of [FakeItEasy 7.3.1](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/releases/7.3.1)**.

---

**Original response, which was wrong, but did ask for more info:**

Likely because a call was made to an unconfigured method on a strict faked repository.

We can't see `DummyAggregateRepository`, so there's going to be some speculation here. Based on the lack of errors earlier, I
assume that `GetById` is virtual or abstract, so your call should be passed to the wrapped instance.

Nothing jumps out at me as I read your question, but this sort of thing usually pops up when

1. a call is made to a different fake object than expected, or
2. a call is made to a different method than expected, usually because there's an overload and the wrong method was configured
3. a call is made to the expected fake object method, but with unanticipated arguments

If you edit your question, supplying

1. the FakeItEasy version you're using
2. the definition of `DummyAggregateRepository`, and
3. the entire exception that's returned, including stack traces

we may be able to help better.

Comment: Thank @Blair Conrad for looking into issue, and detailed explanation. I just realized that test will not work anyway, because second call to .GetEvents virtual method gets called from .GetById, so there is no way to fake this.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the `.GetEvents` in there. You may be better off using `CallsBaseMethod`, which at least keeps you executing on the Fake, but, I expect you'd still be adding an `Invokes` to your configuration of `GetById`. It might get a little messy.

Comment: Actually, being unable to do this made me rethink responsibilities of the class towards better design.